# the meaning of [int] in declaring a vector

Tags: c++, opencv

in the following code : the [2] is used for what?
I do understand that "points" is a vector of 2D points but I do not understand the benefit of "[2]" !!!

```
vector<CvPoint2D32f> points[2];
```

or

```
vector<string> imageNames[2];
```

or

```
vector<CvPoint2D32f> temp(10);
```

and what is the difference between temp(10) and the other kind of brackets ?

Comment: `points` is an array of two `vector<CvPoint2D32f>`s. In the same way as `int twoInts[2];` declares an array of two `int`s.

Comment: This is covered in any introductory C++ book, in the chapters about arrays and vectors, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring an array of vector < CvPoint2D32f >

points[0] is a vector < CvPoint2D32f >

points[1] is a vector < CvPoint2D32f >

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
vector<CvPoint2D32f> points[2];
```

you declare an array of vectors with length 2.
`points[0]` and `points[1]` are `vectors` of `CvPoint2D32f`.
In line

```
vector<CvPoint2D32f> temp(10);
```

you declare one vector containing 10 elements of `CvPoint2D32f` type.